# ~/Maildir vs /var/mail for e-mail storage

Tags: email-server, exim, dovecot, maildir

I run a mail server with Exim4 and Dovecot.  Currently mail goes to ~/Maildir.  However, I am wondering what the relative advantages and disadvantages of storing mail in /var/mail/$user/ is.

Is one location more secure (from a process privileges standpoint) or standard than the other?  In both instances I am referring to using the Maildir as oppposed to mbox storage format,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a matter of personal choice, but generally speaking I prefer to use `~/.mbox` for mbox format stuff, and `~/.mail/` or `~/.maildir/` for maildirs - the reason being that it keeps the user's mail with the rest of the user's files, and makes backing things up much easier (if I grab the spot where the home directories live I get everything at once).

Courier IMAP seems to use locations under `~/` by default last I checked.

Bear in mind that the location affects [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) configuration, so if you change it make sure that your users' `.procmailrc` files & system procmail configuration are updated accordingly.